# Send email using PhoneGap on iphone Application

Tags: iphone, email, cordova

I wan to send email using phoneGap in iphone Application. Any Idea.

Comment: Yes I have found the plugin for this:

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins

Comment: If you received a satisfying answer, it would be nice to reckon that to the answerer!

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by using a phonegap plugin called emailcomposer which can be found on github: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/EmailComposer